# Reuse colors in xml while defining Jetpack Compose Theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I know that with Jetpack Compose I can define colors in Kotlin files.
Since I'm migrating an app that used not to use Jetpack Compose, I'd like to keep pointing to the colors in the XML until I get rid of all the places when I'm already using them.

I know that I can use `colorResource` in a @Composable function but I can't do it when I define the palette in a Kotlin file.

Is it possible to do something equivalent to this?

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = colorResource(id = R.color.company),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Depending on the scope of what you want to reuse, you could also consider [Accompanist's AppCompat theme adapter](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/appcompat-theme).

Comment: thank you @CommonsWare. I googled it and I didn't find anything. That is what I was expecting to find. It is still a WIP though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I did it is by using @Composable functions even for the definitions of the colors:

```
@Composable
fun darkColorPalette() = darkColors(
    primary = colorResource(id = R.color.company),
)
```

Comment: I was intending to use outside Composable context, `colorResource` doesn't work there